# each half or every half?

Tags: each-every

If I want to tell that during football game there was 5 minutes of additionls time in first half and sam in second half which of the following sentences would be correct and why?

*"5 minutes of additional time in each half"*
or
*"5 minutes of additional time in every half"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As there are only **two** halves of anything, it is most logical to say "**both** halves".

'Each' can be used for 2 or more things, so you could also use this and it would be quite idiomatic in your specific context.

'Every' is used for *more than 2* things, or things which are expected to recur in the future (eg 'every day').

Comment: Very nice answer

Comment: I'm not convinced *it is most logical to say "both halves"* in OP's or similar contexts. *I gave £10 to both boys* is potentially ambiguous as to whether I gave them £10 ***each*** or ***in total, between them***. Perhaps that's a *little* less likely with OP's exact example, but I still think it's a potential "ambiguity pitfall" that learners should take note of.

Comment: ..that's to say, ***in principle*** the word "both" is more precise than "each" or "every", because it always implies ***exactly two*** referents. But it often risks creating ambiguity when it muddies the ***separately / collectively*** distinction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not really. If I said "I've seen both Grease movies" would you think that meant I'd watched them at the same time? It would be weird to say I'd seen 'each'.

Comment: It's decidedly abnormal to watch two movies at the same time (even if they both have the same name! :) so no-one would be likely to misunderstand that one. But there's nothing unusual about giving a specified amount of money to two people *collectively* as opposed to *apiece*.

Comment: What if it says: 10 minutes of additionls time was added in total. 5 minutes in each half. does using  **each** is better here than using **both**?

Comment: No, I feel this is entirely wrong.  If somebody said to me _"there are five additional minutes in both halves"_, then this is unclear, and my next question to them would be _"do you mean five minutes in total, or five minutes in each half"_.  The correct answer to this question is _each_, not _both_.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it's also "decidedly abnormal" to play two halves of a sports game at the same time. And to spread 5 minutes of extra time *across* two halves of a game.